# Katalon suite execution via Jenkins error

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

I'm trying to execute my test suite via Jenkins using Firefox headless but I keep getting an error and I can't figure out how to solve it.
This is the console log:

> [Parent 5024, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 232: file
> z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 513
>
> #### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008D,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel
>
> error: cannot send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150080,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set,
> shutting down 1524986830246   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method
> shutdown on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.1
> 1524986830246 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org version 80
> 1524986830248 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> screenshots@mozilla.org version 25.0.0
> 1524986830248 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> onboarding@mozilla.org version 1.0
> 1524986830250 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> formautofill@mozilla.org version 1.0
> 1524986830250 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> followonsearch@mozilla.com version 0.9.6
> 1524986830250 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
> 1524986830250 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
> 1524986830250 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on
> activity-stream@mozilla.org version 2018.02.17.0026-173e2795
>
> #### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008D,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel
>
> error: cannot send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150080,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set,
> shutting down 1524986831912   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57334
>
> #### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x15008D,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateNativeWindowHandle) Channel
>
> error: cannot send/recv
>
> #### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x150080,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
>
> send/recv
>
> A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set,
> shutting down 1524986840082   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
> 1524986840082 addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for
> XPIProvider 1524986840082 addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
> 1524986840084 addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
> 1524986840084 addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for
> LightweightThemeManager 1524986840084 addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling
> shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
> 1524986840084 addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for
> PluginProvider 1524986840086  addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown
> blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
> 1524986840090 addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
> *** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for
> id: telemetry_modules_ping JavaScript error:
> chrome://marionette/content/server.js, line 337:
> NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001
> (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIServerSocket.close] 04-29-2018 07:27:20
> AM - [FAILED] - Unable to open browser with url:
> 'URL' (Root cause:
> version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time:
> driver.version: CGeckoDriver remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:    0:
> 0x4821c4 -     1:           0x482933 -     2:
> 0x47a13a -     3:           0x47abb0 -     4:
> 0x44bb74 -     5:           0x43026a -     6:
> 0x40ba4e -     7:           0x4119b9 -     8:
> 0x6d2c89 -     9:           0x426006 -    10:
> 0x6cd490 -    11:     0x7ffe8a768364 - BaseThreadInitThunk)

Btw, I successfully executed the same suite in console mode via cmd.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you execute testsuite from your local computer in headless mode? Is execution successful?

Comment: Chrome headless - works both on the cmd and on Jenkins (localhost)
Fireox headless - works only from the cmd and not on Jenkins(localhost)

Comment: Provide path of geckodriver in the script: `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user/Desktop/geckodriver")` You can find geckodriver here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases